# Distribution of the lengths of edges of the Delaunay triangulation?

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request, triangulation

Consider the unit square $I^2 = [0,1]^2$ and suppose we have choose $n$ points at random from $I^2$ where the points are taken from the uniform distribution on $I^2$. Call this space $X_{n}$. Can anyone recommend to me any papers that deal with the probability distribution of the lengths of the Delaunay triangulation on $X_{n}$?